# Terraform Modules - Unable to Access variable from root

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-openstack

I am trying to pass a variable from the root module to a child module with the following syntax and i'm unable to do that:

```
└── Terraform
            ├── main.tf
            ├── variable.tf
    └── module
                ├──main.tf
                ├── variable.tf
```

Terraform Version:

```
Terraform v0.11.11
+ provider.openstack v1.15.0
```

**Terraform Configuration Files**
/Terraform/main.tf:

```
provider "openstack" {
openstack_user_name         = "${var.openstack_user_name}"
openstack_tenant_name   = "${var.openstack_tenant_name}"
openstack_password      = "${var.openstack_password}"
openstack_auth_url          = "${var.openstack_auth_url}"
domain_name             = "${var.domain_name}"
}
module "testMod" {
name                    = "${var.name}"
imageId                     = "${var.imageId}"
flavor_name                 = "${var.flavor_name}"
openstack_keypair   = "${var.openstack_keypair}"
tenant_network_id           = "${var.tenant_network_id}"
tenant_network      = "${var.tenant_network}"
source = "./modules"
}
```

/Terraform/variable.tf:

```
variable "name" {default = "XXX"}
variable "imageId" {default = "11-22-33"}
variable "flavor_name"{default = "flavor"}
...
```

/Terraform/modules/main.tf:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "test" {
 name               = "${var.name}"
imageId                 = "${var.imageId}"
flavor_name             = "${var.flavor_name}"
openstack_keypair       = "${var.openstack_keypair}"
security_groups     =   ["default"]

network {
tenant_network_id       = "${var.tenant_network_id}"
tenant_network      = "${var.tenant_network}"
    }
}
```

/Terraform/modules/variable.tf:

```
variable "name" {}
variable "imageId" {}
variable "flavor_name" {}
variable "openstack_keypair" {}
variable "tenant_network_id"{}
variable "tenant_network" {}
```

#### Actual Behavior

`Error: module.testMod.openstack_compute_instance_v2.test: : invalid or unknown key: imageId`

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. `terraform init`
2. `terraform apply`

Unsure what is going wrong here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is alerting you to the unknown key`imageId`. This message is accurate as, in fact, the key should be `image_id`. You can check the Terraform [openstack_compute_instance_v2](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/openstack/r/compute_instance_v2.html) resource documentation and note the presence of the [image_id](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/openstack/r/compute_instance_v2.html#image_id) argument.

Your code would then look like:

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "test" {
  name              = "${var.name}"
  image_id          = "${var.imageId}"
  flavor_name       = "${var.flavor_name}"
  openstack_keypair = "${var.openstack_keypair}"
  security_groups   = ["default"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this requirement to access variables from root variable.tf inside module/myservice/main.tf

How can we achive that ? By using var.environmentdoes not work

e.g:

root/variable.tf

```
variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "Resource environment e.g dev, test or prod."
  default     = "dev"
}
```

How to access above variable var.environment in root/module/myservice/main.tf using ${var.environment} does not work.

root/module/myservice/main.tf

```
locals {
  name = "${var.environment}.myInstance"
}
resource "aws_network_interface" "foo" {
  name = local.name
  .
  .
  .
}
```